# Is every integer a difference of two powers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

True or false? (I don't know.) Every positive integer is the difference of two powers. Examples:
 $ 1 = 3^2 - 2^3 $
 $ 2 = 3^3 - 5^2 $
 $ 3  = 2^7-5^3 $
 $ 4 = 2^3-2^2 = 5^3-11^2 $
 $ 5 = 2^5 - 3^3 $
 $ 6 = ? $
 $ 7 = 2^5-5^2 $
 $ 8 =? $
 $ 9 = 5^2-2^4 $

Comment: I don't think this question is as bad as it seems. It is clear that every integer not congruent to $2$ mod $4$ is a difference of two powers (namely two squares). However, for integers congruent to $2$ mod $4$ the answer is not clear to me.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page on Catalan's conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), $6$ is not the difference of two powers. I would be delighted to see a proof of this result.

Comment: @GHfromMO: On the other hand, I am ready to bet my money that the OP meant this as recreational mathematics, and that throwing hard mathematics at it would only confuse him.

Comment: @GHfromMO: If $n=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, since $a-b\equiv a+b\ \pmod 2$, $n$ is either odd or divisible by 4. I doubt that this is at research level...

Comment: @abx: The equation is not $n=a^2-b^2$ but $n=a^p-b^q$. It is definitely of research level, see the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: According to a 2004 preprint by Waldschmidt it is not known whether $6$ is a difference of two powers. See the paragraph below Corollary 1.3 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312440.pdf

Comment: I totally agree with GH from MO. The question is indeed formulated in a rather amateurish way but is extremely interesting and does deserve attention from experts in number theory.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that the underlying diophantine equation $a^p-b^q=n$ is called Pillai's equation. It has been investigated for decades and from many angles.

Comment: @stephen gray : I took the liberty to improve the formulation of your question to make it look more professional and help it get the attention it deserves.

Comment: It's a notoriuos open problem, right? Don't we generally close such questions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It is a notorious open problem to say anything about the solutions of a single equation $a^p-b^q=n$ (where $a,b,p,q$ are all variables). On the other hand, it might be more accessible to show that the equation has no solution for some $n$ (without specifying this $n$), and that would answer the OP's question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: If the asker doesn't appear to know that it's an open problem, then I think common practice has been to post an answer saying "it's an open problem" and giving some references.

Comment: Well, anyway, I can fill in one of the blanks: $8=2^3-0^3$. If use of zero is objectionable, then $8=2^4-2^3$. https://oeis.org/A074981 tabulates a conjectured list of positive integers not a difference of two powers; it begins 6, 14, 34, 42, 50, 58, 62, 66, 70, 78, 82, 86, 90.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I am not sure the OP's question (whether there exists an integer which is not the difference of two powers) has been emphasized in the literature. I don't think it is easier than the usual questions around Pillai's equation, but still.

Comment: Closely related (pun intended) is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283903. Gerhard "Get It? 'Closely Related'.  Ha." Paseman, 2018.04.11.