# Difference of powers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Prove or disprove: Any positive integer N can be expressed as N=a^x-b^y with a,b,x,y >1. (I don't know the answer or whether this conjecture has been addressed.)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297601/is-every-integer-a-difference-of-two-powers

Comment: Unfortunately, this post cannot be closed as a duplicate because the other question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known open conjecture. See [this Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences entry](http://oeis.org/A074981) for references.